# How to convert sql to LINQ combine LEFT JOIN, WHERE, GROUP BY and SUM in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

My sql query :

```
SELECT 
    a.`ItemCode`, a.`UnitCost`, a.`UOM`, a.`Description`,
    SUM(b.QtyIN) AS 'Total', a.`UnitCost` AS 'Adjusted cost' 
FROM 
    stk_master AS a 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM stk_detail_trn_in 
     WHERE `LocationCode` = 'PGV001' 
       AND `DocType3` = 'OS-NSI') AS b ON a.`ItemCode` = b.`ItemCode` 
GROUP BY 
    a.`ItemCode`;
```

This is LINQ query:

```
var data = (from e in master
            join d in stockIn on e.ItemCode equals d.ItemCode into table1
            from d in table1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where d.LocationCode == id && d.DocType3 == "OS-NSI"
            select new ViewModelListInventory
                    {
                        stk_master = e,
                        stk_detail_trn_in = d,
                    })
        .GroupBy(x => x.stk_detail_trn_in.ItemCode) 
        .Select(d => new stk_detail_trn_in { QtyIN = d.Sum(x => x.stk_detail_trn_in.QtyIN)})
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Please provide your SQL query to check. It is little unclear. Please update your question. :)

Comment: this is my sql query : SELECT a.ItemCode,a.UnitCost,a.UOM,a.Description,SUM(b.QtyIN) AS 'Total', a.UnitCostAS 'Adjusted cost' FROM stk_master AS a LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM stk_detail_trn_in WHERELocationCode= 'PGV001' ANDDocType3 = 'OS-NSI') AS b ON a.ItemCode = b.ItemCode GROUP BY a.ItemCode;

Comment: Ok . Let me check.

Comment: There is problem in you `group by`. You are trying group by using one column but in the select  section you have  a.`UnitCost`, a.`UOM`, a.`Description`,a.`UnitCost` AS 'Adjusted cost'  which might not work in sql server. Please correct your SQL. :)

Comment: As mentioned above this is invalid SQL, so converting to LINQ has no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```cs
var query = 
   from e in master
   join d in stockIn.Where(d => d.LocationCode == id && d.DocType3 == "OS-NSI") on e.ItemCode equals d.ItemCode into table1
   from d in table1.DefaultIfEmpty()
   group d by new { e.ItemCode } into g
   select new 
   {
       g.Key.ItemCode,
       Total = g.Sum(x => x.QtyIN)
   };
```